# JSONObject error when executing code to update remote JSON file

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, parsing

I am trying to update a JSON file with input from an HTTP GET request. I so far have the following below but it is returning an `org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject`. I have tried numerous methods with this but I am hitting the same hurdle and going round in circles. Please help me.

The goal after seeing the revised JSON data outputted to system is to write it back to file.

HTTP GET RESPONSE FORMAT:

```
{
array: [
"data1" : "data 1",
"data2" : "data 2",
"data3" : "data 3",
"data4" : "data 4",
"data5" : "data 5",
]
}
```

EXISTING JSON FILE (please note no array):

```
{
"data5" : "data 5",
"dataA" : "data A",
"dataB" : "data B",
"dataC" : "data C",
"dataD" : "data D",
}
```

HTTP GET CODE:

```
@Component
public class ServiceConnector {

    private final HttpClient client;

    public ServiceConnector() {
        client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    }

    public String get(String url, String acceptHeader, Optional<String> bearerToken) throws UnauthorizedException {
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.addHeader("Accept", acceptHeader);
        if (bearerToken.isPresent()) {
            request.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken.get());
        }

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

//new code
String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("results");
for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {

JSONObject jsonResult = results.getJSONObject(i);

OBLI Result = new OBLI();
String data1 = jsonResult.getString("data1");
String data2 = jsonResult.getString("data2");
String data3 = jsonResult.getString("data3");
String data4 = jsonResult.getString("data4");
String data5 = jsonResult.getString("data5");

try {
FileReader reader = new FileReader("/root/Desktop/data.json");

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
System.out.println(jsonObject);

JSONObject dataObj = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("data5");
System.out.println(periodObj);

dataObj.put("data5",data5);

System.out.println(jsonObject);

}

catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
       } catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
//end of new code

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 401) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException();
            }
            return "something else later";
}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with "**HTTP GET RESPONSE FORMAT**".
maybe right JsonArray format is:-
{
"array": [{
"data1" : "data 1",
"data2" : "data 2",
"data3" : "data 3",
"data4" : "data 4",
"data5" : "data 5"
}]
and then you can change 
**JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("results");** to **JSONArray results = root.getJSONArray("array");**
and then use for-each loop for get one by one Object With help of DTOs.
}
So, you can convert jsonArray to JsonObject.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I resolved this. It seems there was a confliction between libraries. Apparently `org.json` and `org.json.simple` do not create `JSONObjects` that are compatible with eachother. To parse the file I used Jackson library and `ObjectMapper` / `JsonNode` and `ObjectNode` in the end.

Comment: Also, sorry, I should have shared my imports.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was that `org.json` and `org.json.simple` did not create `JSONObjects` that were interchangeable.

I used Jackson library and `ObjectMapper`, `JsonNode`, and `ObjectNode` to update the file - ultimately removing the `org.json.simple` library altogether.